# How to fill the gap with %20 in Url in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have tried with WebUtility.UrlEncode and Uri.UnescapeDataString but it is encoding the whole url but i want only the gap(space) to fill with %20. My code is below.

```
string url = "https://www.example.com/images/catalog/operators/Ajmer Vidyut Vitran Nigam.png";
 //Method1
 string imageUrl = WebUtility.UrlEncode(url);

 //Method2
 string temp = Uri.EscapeDataString(url);
```

Actual url after encoding:    "https%3A%2F%2Fassetscdn.paytm.com%2Fimages%2Fcatalog%2Foperators%2FAjmer+Vidyut+Vitran+Nigam.png"

Expected url:
"https://assetscdn.paytm.com/images/catalog/operators/Ajmer%20Vidyut%20Vitran%20Nigam.png"

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: if you want just to replace the spaces: `url.Replace(" ", "%20");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Uri.EscapeUriString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string imageUrl = Uri.EscapeUriString(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode Method (String). Check more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.105).ASPx)